# How to show multiple names for one record but not duplicate the record?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php

I have a database structure like so:

```
Car
 - id   
 - carname
 - image
 - category
 - status

Parts
 - partid
 - partname

CarParts
 - carpartid
 - carid(fk)
 - partid(fk)
 - amountid(fk)

Category
 - id
 - categoryname

Amount
 - amountid
 - amountvalue
```

Right now this is what I am working on:

```
SELECT * FROM carparts
INNER JOIN car on carparts.carpartid = car.id 

INNER JOIN parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid

INNER JOIN amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
```

This returns duplicate records when there is more than one carpart in the carparts table. How can I combine the carparts.id and car.id to one row but still have multiple partname for that one record?

So what has to happen is that each car could have multiple car parts but when the query runs if there is more than one car part for one record it shows duplicate records with different partnames is there a way to have to one car with many partnames for that record?

Do i have to change the database structure or the query to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you structure looks good . except that you could merge the amount to the part table . as every part is strictly associates with price.

also, only reason you will have duplicate rows is if any of your dimensions tables do not follow strict primary constraints.

```
Car
 - id (pk)
 - carname
 - image
 - category
 - status

Parts
 - partid (pk)
 - partname
 - amountValue

CarParts
 - carpartid (pk)
 - carid(fk)
 - partid(fk)
 - amountid(fk)

Category
 - id (pk )
 - categoryname
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the `*` is only for demonstration purposes.

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to aggregate strings from several rows into one string. In the example below I only include carname, you probably want some more info:

```
SELECT c.carname
     , GROUP_CONCAT(p.partname)
FROM carparts as cp
JOIN car as c 
    ON cp.carid = c.id 
JOIN parts as p 
    ON p.partid = cp.carpartid
JOIN amount as a 
    ON a.amountid = cp.amountid 
WHERE c.status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what the full relationships are or sample data, try this FK correction first to see if it fixes the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM carparts
INNER JOIN car on carparts.carid = car.id 
INNER JOIN parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid
INNER JOIN amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid 
WHERE status = 1
```